# Global constants undefined in constructor

Tags: c++, header-files

I have two files for constants:

```
// constants.h
extern const std::string testString;

// constants.cpp
const std::string testString = "defined!";
```

I need to use this constant in the constructor of an object when the program is initialised, but it comes as undefined. 
The code in the constructor is:

```
MyClass::MyClass() {
   printf("Value of test string: %s", testString.c_str());
}

// output:
Value of test string: (null)
```

The class and the constants are defined in the same namespace, and it does not give me an error that the constant is undefined. After the object is initialised (e.g. with a hard-coded string), it works fine and prints out the value of the constant ("defined!"). Primitive constants seem to work fine in the constructor.

I think it has something to do with the constant not being initialised at that time (so from the .cpp file). 
Do you know why this might happen? Does the initialisation of extern const occur after the program fully initialises?

Thank you in advance

**EDIT:**

Note that the `string` type is to simplify the issue, so converting it to `char` is not an option as I am also interested in having other non-primitive types too.

Code for a minimal dirty example of a program that shows this issue:

```
// constants.h
extern const std::string testString;

// constants.cpp
#include "constants.h"

const std::string testString = "defined!";

// MyClass.h
class MyClass {

public:
    MyClass();
    virtual ~MyClass();
};

// MyClass.cpp
#include "MyClass.h"
#include "constants.h"

MyClass::MyClass() {
   printf("Value of test string: %s\n", testString.c_str());
}

MyClass::~MyClass() {}

// main.cpp
#include "MyClass.h"
#include "constants.h"

MyClass my;            // undefined string (outputs null)

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    MyClass my;        // defined string
    return 0;
}
```

**EDIT 2:**

The solution in this case was to define an static inline function in the header file, as [@Brian](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53306465/4530384) and [@LightnessRacesinOrbit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53306465/4530384) suggested. They both contributed to the final answer.

Here is the code:

```
inline std::string getTestString() { return "defined!"; }
```

This allows to have non `constexpr` types as global constants.

Comment: Show the smallest program you can come up with that compiles, runs, and illustrates the problem. Unless, of course, in the process of reducing your actual code to the simplest example you see what's going wrong.

Comment: @PeteBecker This question was for me to understand why it happens, not to have somebody fix my code, so I only added the relevant parts. Regardless, I added the code if you'd like to try it.

Comment: "Why it happens" often depends on "what it's doing"; people can make guesses from code fragments, but can't give definite answers. It's quite common to see code fragments that have nothing wrong; the programmer didn't know enough about the problem to identify the critical parts. The other thing is, in reducing code to the smallest example that shows the problem, you'll often see it for yourself. That's an important skill.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Within* the `constants.cpp` translation unit, `testString` will be initialized before any subsequently defined non-local variable. *Between* translation units, we have what's called the "static initialization order fiasco"; any translation unit other than `constants.cpp` cannot assume that `testString` has been initialized until after `main` has started executing, so if it tries to read its value during one of its own non-local initializations, then it may observe a zero-initialized `std::string` object, which has undefined behaviour.

My suggestion to avoid this problem, which is also the rule followed at my former workplace, is that if you must have global constants, make them `constexpr` if possible, and be very wary of having any non-`constexpr` global variables. `std::string` isn't `constexpr` (yet), but an old-fashioned `char` array could work:

```
// constants.h
inline constexpr char testString[] = "defined!";

// constants.cpp
// no need to define `testString` here!
```

Comment: Hi, I thought it had something to do with the order of initialisation, so thanks for confirming it. However, I think the `inline` keyword is C++17 and I am unfortunately on C++14 for this issue (correct me if wrong). I will keep looking at what to do. Thanks again!

Comment: @Colmike Function-statics can be useful. Failing that, avoid globals!

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Thanks for that! That helped solving the issue. I used inline functions in the header file and it prints the defined value. This seems to be a way to handle non `constexpr` types (e.g. `string`) directly. I will have to check how feasible this is in the long run for many application-wide globals though

Comment: @Colmike Nice one! Right on all counts. I do agree you should think hard about whether it will scale for you but it works in a pinch. Ideally I think you would leave the constants where they are and fix `my` being a global but it's not always so easy.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Making `my` not global would also fix this issue, but in my case, this is one `main.cpp` of many (the application is a cross-platform library) and I only have access to the Linux main. I do not know if changing this is viable for other teams that may have a different API. Thanks for that, I will check.

Comment: @Colmike In C++14, you can just do `constexpr char testString[] = ...` and it'll still work, but the object will have internal linkage, so there will be one copy per translation unit. (This is usually ok, but sometimes you may want a unique address, or you'll be targeting some embedded platform where memory is very scarce.)

Comment: @Brian Yeah, that's what I do for ints and other primitives as that's not an issue. The problem was with non-primitive types like strings or vectors. I couldn't find anything for these types and I was wondering how initialisation worked in C++. Thanks!